# Order of (:before/:after) method invocation in CLOS?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

I need some help understanding the order of execution for the following code.

I create an instance of `pie`, using the following:

```
(cook (make-instance 'pie))
```

I know lisp executes functions from most specific to least specific.. however, it doesn't look like that is being followed after `(defmethod cook ((p pie))` is called.

I would assume  `(defmethod cook :after ((f food))` & `(defmethod cook :after ((p pie))` to be executed in opposite order, since our instance is of `pie`, and not the parent class, `food`.

Thanks,
any input will be greatly appreciated.

```
(defclass food () ())

(defmethod cook :before ((f food))
  (print "A food is about to be cooked."))

(defmethod cook :after ((f food)) 
  (print "A food has been cooked."))

(defclass pie (food)
  ((filling :accessor pie-filling
            :initarg :filling 
            :initform 'apple)))

(defmethod cook ((p pie))
  (print "Cooking a pie.")
  (setf (pie-filling p) (list 'cooked (pie-filling p))))

(defmethod cook :before ((p pie))
  (print "A pie is about to be cooked."))

(defmethod cook :after ((p pie)) 
  (print "A pie has been cooked."))
  (setq pie-1 (make-instance 'pie :filling 'apple))
```

With output such as :

```
"A pie is about to be cooked." 
"A food is about to be cooked." 
"Cooking a pie." 
"A food has been cooked." 
"A pie has been cooked." 
(COOKED APPLE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [section 7.6.6.2 (Standard Method Combination) of the Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_ffb.htm). Here's the most relevant passage:

> The before methods are run in most-specific-first order while the
>   after methods are run in least-specific-first order. The design
>   rationale for this difference can be illustrated with an example.
>   Suppose class C1 modifies the behavior of its superclass, C2, by
>   adding before methods and after methods. Whether the behavior of the
>   class C2 is defined directly by methods on C2 or is inherited from its
>   superclasses does not affect the relative order of invocation of
>   methods on instances of the class C1. Class C1's before method runs
>   before all of class C2's methods. Class C1's after method runs after
>   all of class C2's methods.

Comment: You could also mentionned [the 2nd Edition of the Standard](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node285.html#SECTION003217200000000000000). I find it more easy to read.

Comment: CLtL is surely an interesting additional document to read about Common Lisp concepts, though the both editions of it are intermediate steps during the standard process, whereas the CLHS is based upon its final result, the actual standard.

Comment: @Rörd: oh I didn't know that, does it mean that CLtL isn't up to date in every subjects and thus some differences or errors might exist ?

Comment: @Daimrod: Yes, some changes have been made after the publication of CLtL2. But it was already quite close to the standard, so you should be safe if you stay away from more esoteric functionality.

Comment: @Daimrod: the Ansi Standard is a quite different text. CLtL2 is interesting, but it describes some prior language. For example the functions to access environments did not make it into the standard. It also is puzzling since it is written as CLtL1 plus annotated changes, plus even more additions which never made it into the standard.

Answer (score 3):

- The primary methods are executed most-specific first, then the next specific via `CALL-NEXT-METHOD`.
- the `:before` methods are executed most-specific-first.
- the `:after` methods are execute least-specific-first.